# Writing a filtered CSV file to a new file and iterating through a folder

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying initially to create a program to go through one file and select certain columns that will then be moved to a new text file. So far I have

```
    import os, sys, csv
    os.chdir("C://Users//nelsonj//Desktop//Master_Project")
    with open('CHS_2009_test.txt', "rb") as sitefile:
    reader = csv.reader(sitefile, delimiter=',')
    pref_cols = [0,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20,22,24,26,30,34,36,40]

    for row in reader:
        new_cols = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
        print new_cols
```

I have been trying to use the csv functions to write the new file but I am continuosly getting errors. I will eventually need to do this over a folder of files, but thought I would try to do it on one before tackling that.

Code I attempted to use to write this data to a new file

```
    for row in reader:
        with open("CHS_2009_edit.txt", 'w') as file:
            new_cols = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
            newfile = csv.writer(file)
            newfile.writerows(new_cols)
```

This kind of works in that I get a new file, but in only prints the second row of values from my csv, i.e., not the header values and places commas in between each individual character, not just copying over the original columns as they were.

I am using PythonWin with Python 2.6(from ArcGIS)

Thanks for the help!

**NEW UPDATED CODE**

```
   import os, sys, csv

   path = ('C://Users//nelsonj//Desktop//Master_Project')

   for filename in os.listdir(path):

       pref_cols = [0,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20,22,24,26,30,34,36,40]
       with open(filename, "rb") as sitefile:
           with open(filename.rsplit('.',1)[0] + "_Master.txt", 'w') as output_file:
               reader = csv.reader(sitefile, delimiter=',')
               writer = csv.writer(output_file)
               for row in reader:
                   new_row = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
                   writer.writerow(new_row)
                   print new_row
```

Getting list index out of range for the new_row, but it seems to still be processing the file. Only thing I can't get it to do now is loop through all files in my directory. Here's a hyperlink to  [Screenshot of data text file](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2081/7r7l.png)

Comment: that means your header file does not have as many columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose of filtering, you don't have to treat the header differently from the rest of the data. You can go ahead remove the following block:

```
    headers = reader.next()
    for row in headers:
        new_header = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
        print new_header
```

Your code did not work because you treated *headers* as a list of rows, but *headers* is just one row.

## Update

This update deals with writing the CSV data to a new file. You should move the `open` statement above the `for row...`

```
with open("CHS_2009_edit.txt", 'w') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for row in reader:
        new_cols = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
        writer.writerows(new_cols)
```

## Update 2

This update deals with the header output problem. If you followed my suggestions, you should not have this problem. I don't know what your current code looks like, but it looks like you supplies a string where the code expects a list. Here is the code that I tried on my system (using my made-up data) and it seems to work:

```
pref_cols = [...] # <<=== Should be set before entering the loop
with open('CHS_2009_test.txt', "rb") as sitefile:
    with open('CHS_2009_edit.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        reader = csv.reader(sitefile, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols)
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

One thing to notice: I use `writerow()` to write a single row, where you use `writerows()` -- that makes a difference.

Comment: I knew I had that working before but in the process of trying to do the write to a new file I deleted some of the working code. Removing this code block worked for that, thanks. The more important question I had, was how do I now move this subset to a new csv file. See the OP for code I tried to do the write with

Comment: I commented out my initial block and add just the above, but it still inserts commas between every character that it reprints out. Is there a way to preserve the column structure of the original file when it creates the new one?

Comment: My last issue then is this, my original "header" row - ['WBAN', 'Date', 'Time', 'SkyCondition', 'Visibility', 'WeatherType'], the new output file looks like this W,B,A,N D,a,t,e T,i,m,e S,k,y,C,o,n,d,i,t,i,o,n V,i,s,i,b,i,l,i,t,y W,e,a,t,h,e,r,T,y,p,e. How do I get the original formatting back?

Comment: I did follow your suggestions, but its having an issue again with the new_row line and list index out of range. Does it matter where the pref_cols is located?

Comment: Thank you for the help you have been giving, wish I could give you a 100 rep points!

Comment: I forgot there were some "one" column comments at the bottom of these files that I believe were causing the index issue. So overall, I believe this issue is taken care of. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 new_header = list(row[i] for i in pref_cols if i in row)
```

That should avoid the error, but it may not avoid the underlying problem.  Would you paste your CSV file somewhere that I can access, and I'll fix this for you?

Comment: Header is fixed, how about writing to new file?